# mystery Internet traffic to port 445

Tags: networking, security, firewall

Recently, I noticed traffic from the office network to TCP port 445 on the Internet [a].  Below are the Linux firewall log entries to Facebook's network [b] and Google's network [c].  I would like to identify the source of this traffic.  My first guess is that Facebook and Google might be using multiple TCP ports for SSL load balancing.  However, I could not confirm this based on the web proxy logs.  What else might it be?

`[a]` http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204279

```
[b]
Sep 4 08:30:03 firewall01 kernel: IN=eth0 OUT=eth2 SRC=10.0.0.131 DST=69.171.237.34 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=14287 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51711 DPT=445 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

[c]
Aug 28 06:02:41 firewall01 kernel: IN=eth0 OUT=eth2 SRC=10.0.0.115 DST=173.194.33.47 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=4558 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49294 DPT=445 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a **very wild guess**, but maybe some program is mistakenly trying to access `\\www.google.com\path` instead of `http://www.google.com/path`?

1. Some websites use scheme-relative URIs such as `//host/path` instead of `http://host/path`. (This is an easy way to make the same link work over both HTTP and HTTPS.)
2. Some programs might incorrectly interpret such a relative URI (`//host/path`) as an UNC address (`\\host\path`).
3. When a program opens an UNC path, Windows tries to access it using SMB (both direct and over NetBIOS) and HTTP/WebDAV.

Comment: Some program or some user, though most I've seen replace the backslash (`\\`) with a forward slash (`/`), not the other way around.

Comment: @afrazier: I have seen a few users typing `http:\\www.example.com\path\path\path`...

Comment: I have seen poorly coded Flash and HTML documents that refer to UNC paths, but have never yet caught them on Facebook or Google.  Every browser I tested accepts http:\\example.com\path and //example.com/path.  When I try \\example.com\path in Internet Explorer, Windows attempts to connect to TCP port 445.  However, it generates more log entries than the "mystery traffic" observed earlier.